# Why is assigning the result of print an invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Simple code:

```
>>> a = print('foo')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = print('foo')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why? Isn't `print` supposed to return `None`? What is so special about `print`?

Nota: there is not much point to this, just trying to understand why this specific function reacts like this.

Comment: you are using python 2 try `python "Hello"`

Comment: @Hackaholic: I don't understand your comment

Comment: in 2 `print "hello"` in 3 print("hello"), yea it will not solve OP question

Comment: Even if this were Python 3, where this is no longer a `SyntaxError`, it's still not particularly useful, because `print` just returns `None` no matter what.

Comment: if you think of `C` program `printf` return the number of character printed. I think @njzk2 want something similar

Comment: @abarnert: I know, I just stumbled upon this as I was trying to get a print in a one-liner

Comment: @njzk2: Well, trying to cram things into a one-liner is a bad idea in general. Trying to bury side-effects in the middle of a larger expression just makes your code less idiomatic, harder to read, and harder to debug. If your functions are too long to read, just refactor them into smaller functions; don't try to "compact" them by playing tricks with syntax. (Not that it can't be fun trying to play "code golf" with Python—but that's only really fun because the language is actively fighting against you, unlike, say, C.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement.  It is not a function and doesn't have a "result".  However, you can make it a function by doing `from __future__ import print_function`, and then your example will work.  (In Python 3 it is always a function.)

Comment: To add to this, `print('foo')` *looks* like a function call, but it's just a parenthesized expression following the `print` keyword.

Comment: that's the part where it look like a function that is confusing.

Comment: @njzk2: You can see the difference if you try to print two arguments: `print 2, 3` will print `2 3`, while `print(2, 3)` is printing one argument, a tuple, so the output will be `(2, 3)`.

Comment: @njzk2: But that's only because you chose to type it that way.  If you type it `print 'foo'` then it doesn't look like a function.

Comment: This statement is probably the single more confusing thing I have yet seen in python (and possibly what I would elect as poorest design, although there was probably a good reason for making it that way)

Comment: @njzk2 Nope, just an old mistake in the language design. That's why they fixed it in Python 3, where `print` is an ordinary function, not dedicated syntax.

Comment: Guido describes the mistake, and why he thinks it's a mistake, in [Python Regrets](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf) (although the slideshow isn't very useful without the talk, which I don't have a link to). And [PEP 3105](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105) has the rationale for fixing it in 3.0, in case it isn't obvious. The most unsolvable problem was that you can't pass keyword arguments to a statement, so `print` had to grow even more special syntax for things like printing to a file or skipping the final newline.